# Inflate layout in a child of a custom listview in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, layout-inflater

I'm working on a custom listview ([libraries](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView)) for my new Android app.
I've a problem to create a custom layout on expand listview.
In fact, the custom listview provided a listener that called onExpand() and onCollapse() to manage this event.

The problem is the inflate layout: doesn't works properly...
The inflate works properly only for first child but doesn't works for other child. Even better, every click on others child duplicate the same layout on first child...

Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
            @Override
            public void onExpand(View itemView, int position)
            {
                LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.expandable);
                LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View addLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_single_row_listview, null);
                mainLayout.addView(addLayout,0);   
            }

            @Override
            public void onCollapse(View itemView, int position)
            {
            }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It's not 'duplicating' (per-say). Your Adapter is actually reusing the Views. In your getView() method, you should either hide (or remove) the added View if it's really necessary for you to inflate it as needed instead of just populating the data and hiding/showing on demand.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a custom libraries (I've posted the link on main post) and "I can't" edit the getView() method, it's too difficult operation for me...I was thinking to build a manual listview and work on getView() method...